# Deploying VulcanJS app with mup on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, meteor-up, mup

I am trying to deploy a VulcanJS app with mup on AWS EC2 instance.

I've set my DNS record type A, for the domain on cloudfare with the IPv4 given by amazon, I followed the instructions given by the Vulcan Documentation and `mup` documentation.
The message logs after running `mup setup` and `mup deploy` where successful, but when trying to connect to the domain or ip nothing happens.

Comment: If nothing happens when connecting to the IP that means your server is not running at all. `mup logs` may provide more information. It is possible that the app is failing on first request for whatever reason, so `mup deploy` would return success message but your app could still crash directly afterward.

Comment: It happened such a long time ago, I gave up on Vulcan